# Filter data with multiple queries flutter firestore

Tags: database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I have a collection of data in firestore and i want to fetch data from it by date and transactionType.
[Firestore collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au5RC.png)

From that collection i want to filter data by date and transactionType and show it in app..
[Filter RadioButtons screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO0Hp.png)

In that image i have radio buttons for date options and transactionType.. I made a function with that i can filter data by transactionType but cant filter by date.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class FilteringScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilteringScreenState createState() => _FilteringScreenState();
}

class _FilteringScreenState extends State<FilteringScreen> {
  String selectedTransactionType = '';
  DateTime? selectedDateFilter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Filtering Screen'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
            onPressed: () async {
              await _showFilterDialog(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildStreamBuilder(),
    );
  }

  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> _buildStreamBuilder() {
    CollectionReference transactions = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('transaction');

    // Build query based on selected filters
    Query filteredQuery = transactions;

    if (selectedTransactionType.isNotEmpty) {
      filteredQuery = filteredQuery.where('transactionType', isEqualTo: selectedTransactionType);
    }

    if (selectedDateFilter != null) {
      filteredQuery = filteredQuery.where('date', isLessThan: selectedDateFilter);
    }

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: filteredQuery.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(child: Text('No data.'));
        }

        var docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
        if (docs.isEmpty) {
          return Center(child: Text('No filtered data.'));
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var data = docs[index];
            // Build UI using data
            // ...

            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['imei']),
              subtitle: Text(data['transactionType']),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showFilterDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Filter Options'),
          content: Column(
            children: [
              // Add your radio buttons and date picker here
              // Similar to what you did in the FilteringScreen
Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: 'In',
                groupValue: selectedTransactionType,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedTransactionType = value.toString();
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text('In'),
              Radio(
                value: 'Out',
                groupValue: selectedTransactionType,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedTransactionType = value.toString();
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text('Out'),
               Radio(
                value: '',
                groupValue: selectedTransactionType,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedTransactionType = value.toString();
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text('All'),
                         ],
          ),
          // Radio buttons for date filters
          Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
                groupValue: selectedDateFilter,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDateFilter = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1));
                    print(selectedDateFilter);
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text('Today'),
              Radio(
                value:DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2)),
                groupValue: selectedDateFilter,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                   selectedDateFilter = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2));
                    print(selectedDateFilter);
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text('Yesterday'),
              Radio(
                value: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7)),
                groupValue: selectedDateFilter,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDateFilter = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7));
                     print(selectedDateFilter);
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text('Week Ago'),
            ],
          ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
                  setState(() {
                    // Update filters based on user selection
                    // You can access the selected values from your radio buttons and date picker
                  });
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

when i select option from both date and transactionType i get some kindda error

> [  +15 ms] W/Firestore(28605): (24.9.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(transaction where transactionType==In and date<time(1706094811,269000000) order by date, **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION,  description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/estock-test-f09cb/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClVwcm9qZWN0cy9lc3RvY2stdGVzdC1mMDljYi9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvdHJhbnNhY3Rpb24vaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaEwoPdHJhbnNhY3Rpb25UeXBlEAEaCAoEZG
>
> [ +706 ms] I/flutter (28605): 2024-01-25 19:13:37.670846 [+2405 ms] W/Firestore(28605): (24.9.1)
>
> [WatchStream]: (52d638e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=Target id not found: 164, cause=null}.

And i want if i havent chosen any option from radioButton i want full collection to be shown in streamBuilder

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with Flutter, but Firebase. Firebase requires creating indexes for some advanced queries (e.g. filtering by two fields at the same time).

The easiest way to create the required indexes, as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) recommends, is to use the link in the returned error. Which, from your error I see it is:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/estock-test-f09cb/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClVwcm9qZWN0cy9lc3RvY2stdGVzdC1mMDljYi9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvdHJhbnNhY3Rpb24vaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaEwoPdHJhbnNhY3Rpb25UeXBlEAEaCAoEZG
```

I do not know if they expire, if they do just try to run the same query and you will get the same error with another link.

Once you visit the link, just follow the instructions, it is pretty straight-forward.